# NumPy - Creation of a counting upper matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, matrix

This is the question: you require an algorithm that asks the user for the the number of rows of a square matrix and then fills the upper triangle of the matrix with counting integers. Your matrix should be a 2D Numpy array.

Notes:

since the matrix is of square size, the number of rows and columns are identical, you may start with initializing the matrix to all zero entries using the appropriate numpy method your algorithm should be using for loops.

Inside the loop, a message should display the current row and column index and the value to be stored at that position.

After the loops have completed, the entire matrix should be displayed
your algorithm will prompt the user for the matrix size and adapt to the size entered

Hint: if you struggle with this task, break it down into easier similar tasks.

These could be:

- fill the entire matrix with values of 1 (in the loop)
- print a square matrix where the entire matrix is filled with increasing integer numbers

Once you have accomplished these tasks, you might have a better idea on how to solve the task in this problem.

This is my code:

```
#input size of matrix from the user
M = int(input('Enter Matrix size: '))
N = M
#The dimension of the matrix in nXm 
dimension = (M, N)


#form a matrix of size nXm
matrix = np.zeros(dimension, dtype=int)

#use the num for filling the values in the matrix
num = 1
#for every row
for i in range (M):
    #the elements before the diagonal are 0 
    for j in range (i+1):
           
        #print ("The value at row  " + str(i) + " and column " + str(j) + " is 0", end = '\n')
    #the elements after the diagonal are num
        for j in range (i,N):
            #print ("The value at row " + str(i) + " and column " + str(j) + " is " + str(num), end = '\n')
            matrix[i][j] = num
        #increase num by 1
        num = num + 1
#print the upper triangular matrix
print (matrix)
```

The matrix it prints is :
[1, 1, 1
0, 3, 3
0, 0, 6]

While the matrix I would like to print is:
[1, 2, 3
0, 4, 5
0, 0, 6]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to generate an upper triangle square matrix.

```
import numpy as np


#input size of matrix from the user
n = int(input('Enter Matrix size: '))


#form a matrix of size nXn
matrix = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)

#use the num for filling the values in the matrix
num = 1
for i in range(n):
    #the elements before the diagonal are 0 
    for j in range(i):
      print (f"The value at row  {i} and column {j} is 0")

    for j in range (i, n):
      print (f"The value at row  {i} and column {j} is {num}")
      matrix[i][j] = num
      num = num + 1

print (f"matrix=\n{matrix}")
```

Output for `n=4`

```
Enter Matrix size: 4
The value at row  0 and column 0 is 1
The value at row  0 and column 1 is 2
The value at row  0 and column 2 is 3
The value at row  0 and column 3 is 4
The value at row  1 and column 0 is 0
The value at row  1 and column 1 is 5
The value at row  1 and column 2 is 6
The value at row  1 and column 3 is 7
The value at row  2 and column 0 is 0
The value at row  2 and column 1 is 0
The value at row  2 and column 2 is 8
The value at row  2 and column 3 is 9
The value at row  3 and column 0 is 0
The value at row  3 and column 1 is 0
The value at row  3 and column 2 is 0
The value at row  3 and column 3 is 10
matrix=
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 0  5  6  7]
 [ 0  0  8  9]
 [ 0  0  0 10]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much I found my mistake with your help!!!